# Как соединить несколько строк в таблице в одну

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

Есть sql запрос

```
select 
   oi.order_item_name , oi.order_item_id, oim.meta_key ,oim.meta_value
from 
   idlf.wp_woocommerce_order_items as oi 
right join 
   idlf.wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as oim 
on 
   oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id 
where 
   oi.order_id = 8133 AND meta_key IN ('_qty', '_line_total','_product_id')
```

Вывод у запроса такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы _product_id, _qty и _line_total были в одной строке к одному и тому же товару?

Comment: сделать 3 join'а... ЗЫ: говорят, в аду есть отдельный котёл для тех, кто вставляет картинки вместо текста...

Comment: @Fat-Zer прошу прощения, исправился

Comment: Да будешь прощён ты всемогущим богом Интернета, да снизайдёт на темя мудрость и благодать его, да будешь находить ответы на все свои вопросы в гугле по первой ссылке и не впадёшь в грех имеджпейтинга боле...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придётся делать 3 `JOIN`'а (или подзапроса, сути не меняет), ничего гламурней для EAV в sql не придумать:

```
SELECT oi.order_item_name , oi.order_item_id,
 oim_qty.meta_value, oim_line_total.meta_value, oim_product_id.meta_value
FROM idlf.wp_woocommerce_order_items AS oi
 LEFT JOIN idlf.wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim_qty 
   ON  oi.order_item_id = oim_qty.order_item_id
   AND oim_qty.meta_key = `_qty`
 LEFT JOIN idlf.wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim_total 
   ON  oi.order_item_id = oim_total.order_item_id
   AND oim_total.meta_key = `_line_total`
 LEFT JOIN idlf.wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim_product_id 
   ON  oi.order_item_id = oim_product_id.order_item_id 
   AND oim_product_id.meta_key = `_product_id`
WHERE oi.order_id = 8133
```

Также, в вопросе, наверно, имелся в виду `LEFT JOIN`. `RIGHT JOIN` мало подходит здесь по смыслу...

Comment: спасибо огромное! Вы очень помогли:)